# Understanding varying mean and repeatability

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeatability, reproducibility

A common introduction in varying parameters looks like that

$y_{ij} = \alpha_{j} + \epsilon_{ij}$, with $\epsilon_{ij} \sim\ N(0, \sigma^2_y)$

$\alpha_{j} = \mu_a + u_j $  and $  u_j \sim\ N(0, \sigma^2_a)$

which can be expressed with the formula `mdl1 <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|a))`

I'was trying to understand how the $\sigma^2_y$ and $\sigma^2_a$ are connected. And how a real example would look like.

some data could be made like this

```
sample_size <- 30
dat <- data.frame
for(i in 1 : 1e1){

  mu <- rnorm(1, 100, 1)
  sig <- rexp(1, .1)
  temp <- rnorm(sample_size, mu, sig)
  temp_df <- data.frame(alpha = rep(as.character(i), sample_size),
                        value = temp)
  if(i == 1) {dat <- temp_df} else { dat <- rbind(dat, temp_df)}
}
```

After @whuber questions for clarifications I figured out that I was just confused.

Please close this question has no value.

Thanks

Comment: The connection between the code and the model is obscure.  Could you please explain what the code is attempting to compute or illustrate and tell us what you mean by a "link"?

Comment: There is a basic problem with trying to use code to express your question: when the code is not executable, as in this instance, we have no reliable way of knowing what you're trying to ask.  Perhaps `mu` was intended to be `mean`?  And taking it to be so, could you tell us what a model of this code would look like?  What would you like to add to it?